# Having relevant .so and binaries inside the venv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, anaconda, mamba

I installed OpenCV using Anaconda, with the following command.

```
mamba create -n opencv -c conda-forge opencv matplotlib
```

I know that the installation is fully functional because the below works:

```
import cv2
c = cv2.imread("microphone.png")
cv2.imwrite("microphone.jpg",c)
import os
os.getpid() # returns 13249
```

Now I try to do the same using C++.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    std::string image_path = "microphone.png";
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    imwrite("microphone.JPG", img);
    return 0;
}
```

And the compilation:

```
> g++ --version
g++ (conda-forge gcc 12.3.0-3) 12.3.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/stetstet/mambaforge/envs/opencv/lib/pkgconfig
> g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

When I run the above, g++ complains that I am missing an OpenGL.

```
/home/stetstet/mambaforge/envs/opencv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/12.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libGL.so.1, needed by /home/stetstet/mambaforge/envs/opencv/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

After some experimentation I discover that some of the libraries must be from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, while others must be used from `/home/stetstet/mambaforge/envs/opencv/lib/` (`opencv` is the name of the venv in use). The following yields an `a.out` which does what was intended:

```
> /usr/bin/g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -lpthread -lrt
```

The `/usr/bin/g++` so that it can actually find `libGL.so.1` as well as `libglapi.so.0`, `libselinux.so.1`, `libXdamage.so.1`, and `libXxf86vm.so.1`. Also, without `-lpthread -lrt` these libraries are used from the venv, which causes "undefined reference to `h_errno@GLIBC_PRIVATE'"

Now, I am very bothered by the fact that I now need to know which one of which library (and g++/ld) I should use. I thought package managers were supposed to handle the dependency mess for us!

Would there be any way to make the compilation command into something like

```
> g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

i.e. have all relevant files or binaries **inside** the venv? For example, is there a way to modify the `mamba create` command (see top) so that this condition is satisfied?

Note: I am tagging both Anaconda, Linux, and OpenCV because I have absolutely no idea what I can use to reach a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `pkg-config` to also be in the env. The following should work:

```
mamba create -n opencv -c conda-forge opencv matplotlib pkg-config
mamba activate opencv
g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Comment: Just in case, I would like to touch upon the fact that **this only ensures the success of compilation, not the execution.** For the binary to be fully functional, users still need to manually set envvars such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as this is not automatically handled by conda/mamba. I feel that this warrants another question, so I will probably write another one.